# Getting Error when trying to upload custom app on MS Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am trying to upload my custom app in MS Teams but I am getting error as attached in image.Earlier I was able to upload the same app in teams but now when I am trying again & getting error.I am trying to upload the app through "Upload a custom app" tab.
[image]

Comment: Could you please confirm if you have added teams scope for your bot?

Comment: I have added Teams channel in the bot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell without seeing the manifest, but are you sure the app (e.g. bot) is set to allow it to be added to a Team per se (versus just a personal or group chat bot)? I'm assuming you're using [App Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/app-studio-overview), and if so when you add/edit the bot you need to confirm the relevant settings are set on the bottom, per this screenshot (personal, team, group chat):

[image]

Comment: adding teams in scope fixed my problem.Thanks

Comment: Great, glad to help